# Why isn't my view variable interpolated inside brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have this code inside my Rails views/comments/_comments partial:

```
 <%= render :partial => 'comments/#{@type}' %>
```

Also, I am passing the `@type` variable through local but I get:

```
Missing partial comments/#{@type}
```

It works if I replace it with the following:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/post' %>
```

so `@type` is not evaluated inside my views.

Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String interpolation in Ruby works only with strings defined with double quotation marks ("). So this should work:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/#{@type}" %>
```

or a shorthand which is applicable if you want to interpolate the value of an instance variable:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/#@type" %>
```

Comment: It works now ,,I am developing on Rails since 3 years ..but I didn't notice that

Comment: @RemonAmin so it's almost three times longer than me. :)
Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: This isn't a Rails issue, it's how Ruby works, along with many other languages. Single-quote delimited lines are fixed and don't allow interpolation of variables. Double-quote delimited lines allow interpolation.

Comment: I think I need to have a refreshment on Ruby again as you pass through Rails you forget the main language and its syntax

Comment: Rails can't break Ruby's syntax otherwise it wouldn't run. It does extend Ruby, and relies on a lot of Ruby's deeper magic to dynamically create methods and variables, but it's still pure Ruby.

Comment: That's why after I started working as Rails developer, I put a lot of effort in learning Ruby.

Comment: +1 @MarekLipka. Too many people try to learn Rails without taking the time to learn Ruby, and, as a result, can't figure out how to do simple things that are basic in Ruby. Once we know Ruby, Rails makes a lot of sense.

Comment: +1 @theTinMan - it also makes debugging much easier, since you can go to Rails source and see how the given method exactly works.